# jQuery on select dropdown updated

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown

First, let me say that I am using a proprietary CMS and I do not have access to source code.

I have the ability to add javascript and/or jQuery and I would like to trigger a function when the options in a select dropdown are updated. Basically, I can get the CMS to populate a dropdown with some amounts and I want to update a total field whenever the dropdown is updated.

I tried `$('.amounts select').on('change', function() { // code here });` but that obviously only fires when the user clicks on the dropdown and makes a selection. I need this to go when the options are updated.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$(document).on('change','.amounts select', function () {
    var total=0.00;
    $('.amounts option').each(function() {
        total+=$(this).val()!="" && $(this).val() != undefined ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0;
    });
    $('.total input').val(total).trigger('change'); 
    console.log('total'+total);
});
```

In case seeing the HTML helps, here it is:

```
<li attr="Amounts" attrtype="select" name="q90" id="q90" data-aid="512" data-mid="518" data-mpath="518" class="amounts form-q label-left">
    <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel90" for="Field90">
        <span>
        <span>Amounts</span>
        </span>
        <span class="screen-reader-legend">field type drop-down</span>
    </label>
    <div class="cf-field">
        <select id="Field90" name="Field90" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel90" class="form-item-field cf-medium" vo="e">
            <option></option>
            <option value="83.30">83.30</option>
            <option value="22.00">22.00</option>
            <option value="705.96">705.96</option>
            <option value="591.50">591.50</option>
            <option value="25.65">25.65</option>
            <option value="198.08">198.08</option>
            <option value="89.41">89.41</option>
            <option value="54.99">54.99</option>
            <option value="278.66">278.66</option>
            <option value="39.09">39.09</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li attr="Total" attrtype="text" name="q91" id="q91" data-aid="513" data-mid="519" data-mpath="519" class="total form-q label-left">
    <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel91" for="Field91">
        <span>
            <span>Total</span>
        </span>
        <span class="screen-reader-legend">field type input</span>
    </label>
    <div class="cf-field">
        <input type="text" id="Field91" name="Field91" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel91" class="input cf-medium" maxlength="1000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e">
    </div>
</li>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share HTML as well?

Comment: *when the options are updated* - there's no easy event for this.   You might be able to hook into where page makes the change - either by overwriting the function that does it or they might have nicely provided an event you can listen for.  You might be able to use a dom mutation observer.

Comment: @Bhautik added HTML

Comment: When option will update?

Comment: @Bhautik the user inputs a userId, the CMS does a lookup to populate their account (including accountId), then the CMS does another lookup to populate the select options. So, in the answer I posted I used that field (accountId) as the trigger but I would have preferred to go off of the actual options being updated.

Answer (score 0):

So, there ended up being 2 options that I came up with to solve this:

1. Use `ajaxComplete` since the CMS is filling the dropdown using an ajax call, so:

   ```
   $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function () {
       // code here
   });
   ```
2. The CMS populates that dropdown based on user input in an another field, so I can do an `.on('change')` for that field and wait maybe 2 seconds before calculating, so:

   ```
   $('#Field10 input').on('change', function () {
       setTimeout(function(){
           // code here
       }, 2000);
   });
   ```

I won't mark this as the correct answer just in case someone comes up with something that uses the select to trigger it.